# how to get the 'droppable' s offset().left and offset().top without using jquery, use raw javascript 

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

for some reason , i can't use jquery .

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >
<style type="text/css">
#draggable
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            color: #333333;
            background: #F2F2F2;
            cursor: move;
            z-index:10;
        }
        #droppable
        {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #E78F08;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #F6A828;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
</style>
<p>
    Eos an invidunt dignissim liberavisse, no paulo alterum vix, mei causae vivendum
    te. Discere omittam ea sed. Est ex mutat aeque discere. Omnes tincidunt pro ea.
    Mentitum expetenda reprehendunt vis id, duo natum adhuc ut. Malis partiendo id duo,
    feugait iudicabit consequuntur at eum.
</p>
<div id="droppable">
    <p>
        Drop here.
    </p>
</div>
<p>
    Ea eam audire antiopam, agam consulatu patrioque no nec. Sea simul insolens ne,
    vero scribentur duo ut. Te mel dico choro virtute. Mel ex sumo omnes.
</p>


<p>
    Eos an invidunt dignissim liberavisse, no paulo alterum vix, mei causae vivendum
    te. Discere omittam ea sed. Est ex mutat aeque discere. Omnes tincidunt pro ea.
    Mentitum expetenda reprehendunt vis id, duo natum adhuc ut. Malis partiendo id duo,
    feugait iudicabit consequuntur at eum.
</p>
<p>
    Ea eam audire antiopam, agam consulatu patrioque no nec. Sea simul insolens ne,
    vero scribentur duo ut. Te mel dico choro virtute. Mel ex sumo omnes.
</p>
<div id="draggable" >
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
<script>
function id(id){
    return document.getElementById(id)
}
console.log(id('droppable').offsetWidth,id('droppable').offsetTop)
id('draggable').style.left =id('droppable').offsetWidth+'px'
id('draggable').style.top = id('droppable').offsetTop+'px'

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/6H5Yj/

so how to set the 'draggable's left Equal the 'droppable's left, top Equal  top,

thanks

Comment: thats mootools, not jQuery ... isn't it?

Comment: you have to listen for events like `mousemove`, `dragstart`, and `dragstop`. - don't know how without jQuery. Well, jQuery is just javascript, dive into it's codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bound = id('droppable').getBoundingClientRect();

var x= bound.left,y= bound.top 

id('draggable').style.left =x+'px'
id('draggable').style.top = y+'px'
```